# C# XNA Paddle ball game

Tags: c#, xna

Hey guy's im making a a paddle ball/pong game and i'm trying to figure out how to make the ball "bounce" away randomly off the paddle like other pong games.

What would the easiest way to do this be?

currently my collision code just makes it bounce of in the other direction (up)

```
public void checkCollision()
{
    Rectangle paddlerect = new Rectangle((int)Paddle.pos.X, (int)Paddle.pos.Y, Paddle.paddle.Width, Paddle.paddle.Height);
    Rectangle ballrect = new Rectangle((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y, ball.Width, ball.Height);

    if (ballrect.Intersects(paddlerect))
    {
        yspeed = 3;
    }
}
```

Could you show me how to make it bounce of randomy to the sides? Like on a diaganol.

Comment: Not knowing the rest of the code this is just a guess but if you have a yspeed variable that determines your vertical speed and direction. Don't you have a xspeed that you can alter in the same manner?

Comment: i have never seen a pong game where "the ball "bounce" away randomly" normally in pong games the balls direction in the Y axis just revert while hitting the paddle. 
if (ballrect.Intersects(paddlerect))
    {
        yspeed = -yspeed ;
    }

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the ball has at least 4 variables :

- Angle
- Magnitude
- XSpeed
- YSpeed

Angle+Magnitude form a [Vector](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Vector), which I'll call v1. 
To make it bounce on a "random" direction (which is never random, actually), you need to use the sinus and cosinus functions. I'm not going back to explain how stuff works in a triangle, but you can use them to calculate every length and angle in it. So you have:

```
XSpeed = v1.Magnitude * cos(v1.Angle);
YSpeed = v1.Magnitude * sin(v1.Angle);
```

If you need to learn more, head on to the [Game Programming Wiki](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/). Seriously, it's really great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a variable called `xspeed` which controls how fast the ball moves to the left or right.

There are 2 main things that pong type games do.

1. Just invert the y speed, as you are doing (in effect).
2. Invert the y speed, but also change the x speed depending on where on that 'bat' the ball hit. i.e. hitting the ball on the far right would make it bounce right.

For option 2 you could either A) set xspeed directly based on how far from the middle the ball hit, or B) you could add/subtract from xspeed depending on how far from the middle the ball was.

```
var relativemidpoint = (ball.left + ball.width/2) -
                       (paddle.left + paddle.width/2);

// Option A
xspeed = relativemidpoint / 10; // or some other constant
// Option B
xspeed += relativemidpoint / 10; // or some other constant
```

You may also want to limit xspeed to be in a range so it doesn't get too fast sideways.

If you want the overall speed to be constant then you'll have to scale `yspeed` depending on the value of `xspeed`.